# How to set a css property to a div only if it has only one child using css and react?

Tags: css, reactjs

i want to apply justify-content: center property to Cards Component only when if it only one Card component inside it.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    const order = //some array of objects
    return (
        <Cards>
            {orders.map((order, index) => {
                return (
                    <Card order={order} />
                );
            )}}
        </Cards>
    );
}


const Cards = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: calc(${256 * 1.5});
    padding: 0 calc(50vw - 600px);
    @media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
        width: 100vw;
        padding: 0 calc(50vw - 400px);
    }
`;

const Card = styled.div`
    max-width: 356px;
    height: 256px;
    width: calc(33.33% - 16px);
    @media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
        width: calc(50% - 16px); 
    }
    margin: 8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
`;
```

This works fine when they are many cards. but when there is only one card the card is not centered to the Cards div.

if i add justify-content: center to the Cards div then it works fine when there is only one card. but when multiple cards say three cards in total, the two cards will fit in first row and third card will be in next row with its position centered to cards div.

so i tried adding :only-child selector to the cards div and it still behaves the same with third card centered to the cards div where i would expect it to be positioned just under the first card in first row.

what i have tried is below

```
const Cards = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: calc(${256 * 1.5});
    padding: 0 calc(50vw - 600px);
    @media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
        width: 100vw;
        :only-child { //added this
            justify-content: center;
        }
        padding: 0 calc(50vw - 400px);
    }
`;

const Card = styled.div`
    max-width: 356px;
    height: 256px;
    width: calc(33.33% - 16px);
    @media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
        width: calc(50% - 16px); 
    }
    margin: 8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
`;
```

below is how it looks with code above

```
with three cards
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

with one card
```

[image]
want it to like below

```
with 3 cards
```

[image]

with one card
[image]

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
function Parent() {
    const orders = [] //some array of objects
    return (
        <Cards itemsCount={orders.length}> // item count prop here
            {orders.map((order, index) => {
                return (
                    <Card order={order} />
                );
            )}}
        </Cards>
    );
}


const Cards = styled.div`
    justify-content: ${props => (props.itemsCount == 1 ? "centre" : "flex-start")};
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: calc(${256 * 1.5});
    padding: 0 calc(50vw - 600px);
    @media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
        width: 100vw;
        padding: 0 calc(50vw - 400px);
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

While you probably can do something like that with pure css, you might find it easier to have javascript help out a bit. I'm not sure which css-in-js library you're using, but they usually have a way to dynamically compose multiple styles together. As a generic example:

```js
function Parent() {
    const order = //some array of objects
    return (
        <Cards className={orders.length > 0 ? extraStyle : ''}>
            {orders.map((order, index) => {
                return (
                    <Card order={order} />
                );
            )}}
        </Cards>
    );
}
```